# Bootstrapping AngularJS after all scripts and server data loaded

Tags: angularjs

How can I delay the dynamic bootstrapping process of AngularJS until all scripts and initial server data are fetched (permissions).

Currently I do following:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
    $http.get('get the permissions').
        success(function(data, status) {
            fetchedPermissions = data.content;
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngRoute', 'appName']);
            console.log("angular bootstrapped");
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            console.log("angular bootstrap failed");
        });
});
```

Part of the head:

```
<script src="modernizr-2.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="fastclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
... more scripts ...
<script src="angular-1.2.28.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
... several files containing controllers, directves and so on ...
```

However, after I added more and more external scripts, the app still gets bootstrapped but the angular run part doesn't get called anymore and the page stays blank. However, it works after I reload the page again.
So it seems that not all scripts are fetched before angular's document ready fires.
Any suggestions how to further delay the bootstrapping process?

EDIT:
The problem only occurs on the very first loading of the website. After I hit the reload button, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Have you checked the console after you added the new scripts? If the app stays blank maybe you included some script that broke the javascript execution?

Comment: Yes, I checked the console, permissions are fetched and no errors. After I reload the page, everything works fine. So it seems like a timing problem.

Comment: @JonasH It's not a timing problem, there is no need to change when angular begins the bootstrapping process.

Comment: @Kirill: You are right, it is not a timing problem. I just checked the network timeline in the console and the DOMContentLoaded event gets indeed fired after all scripts are loaded like it suppose to be. But then it's even more odd that it only happens on the very first page load.

Comment: @JonasH Yeah, sorry I can't help much more with just this info :(.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
You can't , you have to bootstrap the app manually.
Remove the `ng-app` attribute or rename it to something else and when your files are done loading bootstrap the app manually.

> EDIT: The problem only occurs on the very first loading of the
>   website. After I hit the reload button, everything seems to be fine.

That's because the second time the files are loaded from the browsers cache.

`document.ready` will not wait for async requests to finish so you can't really rely on it.

you can also use `$q` to know when all resources are loaded and ready to bootstrap the app.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something [like this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data).

Answer (score -1):

> How can I delay the dynamic bootstrapping process of AngularJS until
>   all scripts and server data are fetched.

Angulars bootstrapping process begins automatically on the `DOMContentLoaded` event. All server data has already been loaded far before this. "Server data" is loaded on the web servers side and given back to the user as an html document. Unless by "server data are fetched" you mean that additional data is requested via ajax...

If you want a library like say `modernizr` to load in before angular does, simply place the `<script>` tag calling for modernizer before the tag that calls angular. Which in your code example you are already doing...

If you mean you want your angular to bootstrap after some other javascript code has executed, that's different. First, if you find yourself needing to mess with when angular is loaded that should tell you you're most likely doing something very wrong... But in order to get other javascript to run prior to angulars bootstrapping process you simply need it to run prior to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. The sure fire way of doing this is again, just placing the script ahead of the `<script>` tag that calls angular.

**Your problem is not when angular is being bootstrapped but something else...**